# Can't connect to localhost using Rails server on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've had my Ruby on Rails server running fine for the past few months and when I started it up today I can't connect to it. I've been googling this all day with no solution.

The terminal output when running `rails server` is:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.19 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

so the rails server seems to be running fine.

I've tried connecting to localhost:3000, 0.0.0.0:3000 and 127.0.0.1:3000 and none of them will connect.

When I run `wget http://0.0.0.0:3000` I get a connection refused error and when I check the connection on the port via `lsof -i :3000` the rails server is listening on the port.

I'm confused what the problem is, so any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

When I try to connect using safari I get `Safari Can't Connect to the Server, Safari can't open the page "http://localhost" because Safari can't connect to the server "localhost"`

I get a similar message when trying through Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: what's the actual error you're getting?

Comment: Does `System Preferences|Security & Privacy|Firewall|Firewall Options` look okay? (If you have this enabled.)

Comment: The firewall is turned off

Comment: Try starting the rails server on a different port with `rails s -p 3003` and connect to localhost:3003 ; might throw some light on the issue.

Comment: I've tried on a few different ports and none of them work. I still get the same error when trying to connect via safari.